# Build iOS application package (ipa) without physical device

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a ionic/cordova application. In Android, I can both build for debug and release (self-signed locally) and generate an .apk package to distribute anyone, being quite easy. On the other side, for iOS: I have a friend with an Iphone, and so far impossible to test the application there. We have hundreds of km between us. I have the Xcode and I have tried in the simulator, but I want to try it in a real iOS device. I have even his account (appleid and I can see the iphone), in Xcode I have the User role as iOS Development (tried with Generic Device but also his own iphone version), but I cannot get my app signed to generate the .ipa package (that I would send to him). There are two errors: a) one regarding no profile / device associated with our account b) no valid bundle id. It seems that Xcode needs physically the iphone connected to the Xcode computer.

So, my questions:

1. How can I create the .ipa to distribute (just for testing purposes, I don't mind about the App Store)?
2. In case I subscribe to the Development Team ($99) to be able to publish in App Store, can I generate the .ipa without having any phone connected to the computer?
3. In case I need a physical device, can I just use a 2nd generation iPad (max iOS 9), with the latest Xcode (Mojave), even if it is not listed in the devices "it supports"? (minimum is 5th generation iPad listed in build for)?

Comment: I have same iPad and no you can not use it to build ionic apps on latest xcode:(

Comment: You do have to pay the $99 to install on a remote device.  You can install locally with Xcode without paying, but you can use TestFlight to send builds to remote devices, and TestFlight is included if you're a paid developer.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Thanks. So, I understand that only any of the devices listed in iOS 12, isn't it?